# Data Injected to SQL DB too large in comparaison to Oracle Source

Tags: oracle, azure, csv, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Hello I am using Azure Data Factory to inject data from Oracle to SQL DB, data are extracted in csv format. The problem is in the source I am reading like 10 Go of Data but when they're injected into Azure SQL DB the data size becomes 40 Go.

Is that normal ? and is there a way to lower the destination data size ?

Thank you

Comment: How are you arriving at these numbers?   Data inside a database typically has overhead that does not exist when that data is in a simple csv file.

Comment: @EdStevens when you use data factory you can see on the left the volume of the data read and on the right the data written.

Comment: What do you mean by 10 Go and 40 Go?  Do you mean GB or GiB instead?  Are your row counts the same?  That's more relevant than data size for a migration.

Comment: @JeffRamos yes the row count is the same, and yes I mean GB.

Comment: If you are measuring database sizes before / after, then most likely problem is the size of the transaction log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the table compression level.  If the table has many number columns, SQL Server's [ROW compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/row-compression-implementation?view=sql-server-ver15) is similar to Oracle's default storage style for numbers and should produce a similar storage size to Oracle

[PAGE compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/page-compression-implementation?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=%20For%20each%20page%20that%20is%20being%20compressed%2C,in%20the%20column%20are%20replaced%20by...%20More%20) provides additional compression strategies and may give you ~3X compression.

And if the table has many millions of rows, use a [clustered cloumnstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-design-guidance?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Consider%20using%20a%20clustered%20columnstore%20index%20when%3A%201,of%20data%20with%20minimal%20updates%20and%20deletes.%20) table, and may provide ~10X compression.

Comment: The page compression worked well, but the row compression increased the data size.